# Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'flutter_downloader'

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, appdelegate

I am getting error while create iOS build.
I have tried old answers but not working for me.

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'flutter_downloader'

project/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:3:7
```

AppDelegate.swift - Flutter_downloader code.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import flutter_downloader  // === getting error here... ===
import flutter_uploader
import flutter_local_notifications

FlutterDownloaderPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(registerPluginsDownload)

private func registerPluginsDownload(registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("FlutterDownloaderPlugin")) {
       FlutterDownloaderPlugin.register(with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "FlutterDownloaderPlugin")!)
    }
}
```

Flutter Details :

```
Flutter 2.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git  
Framework • revision c860cba910 (7 months ago) • 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
Tools • Dart 2.16.2 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try to open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj and it will work fine,
if it not works, you can delete pubspec.lock, move to IOS folder, run pod install, than clean project and pub get.

hope these helps.

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried but not working..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error, in my case I have added customised scheme and didn't set proper Build configuration for Profile and Archive options. If you have also added any scheme, kindly check your scheme configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved by adding support email in xcode.