"Flutter/Flutter.h file not found" when trying to archive iOS app using Xcode
I am facing some errors when I am trying to to archive iOS app for uploading to AppStore connect. I selected the Archive option from Product tab in Xcode. The pod installation completes without any error but the build failed. The exact error is shown in the image below.

I have also tried flutter build ios --release command from terminal. But that also ended with an error. The error is very long. But starts with lines as shown in the below image.

I tried several ways like flutter clean, pod disintegrate, and pod install but nothing works.
For better understanding I am attaching the podfile here:
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
   end
  end
 end


did you try removing pod file then commands "cd ios" and "pod install" ? after that restart xcode and then run

Also try pod instal --repo-update after deleting de Pods folder and the Podfile.lock.

No luck. same error. @AlejandroCumpa

No luc@Normal1One

maybe helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74120505/swift-compiler-error-xcode-no-such-module-flutter-downloader.

I guess your Podfile lack one important call to flutter_additional_ios_build_settings. Here is what you can do about it:

Make sure that Flutter itself is up-to-date (3.24.3 at the moment of writing this). If not – I strongly suggest to update.

In your Podfile, add flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) to post_install block, so it'll start to look like this:


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    // Line below is what you should add.
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    // This is your content, I left it untouched, but I'm not sure
    // if it still required though.
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
     end
  end
end


Clean your project. The deeper clean the better, but in my case just flutter clean was enough. But, maybe it's worth to also delete ios/Pods, ios/.symlinks and ios/Podfile.lock.

Build!


These steps were sufficient to solve the problem in my case, hope it'll help you. Good luck!

Thanks a lot. This worked like a magic.
